# ListView with counter badge

Tags: java, android, listview

The sample screenshots for a navigation drawer in the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Style) show a counter badge in a `ListView` (blue background with white "3").
How can I add such a badge with the same look in my application?

Comment: You could simply implement a custom adapter for the drawer's `ListView`.

Comment: But how to achieve the same look?

Comment: A rounded blue shape for the background + setting the text color to white(maybe also bold-ing the text)?

Comment: So there's no standard way to do that? I've to draw the background myself?

Comment: No, this is a design problem more then anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You would provide a custom Layout in a custom adapter for your ListView.

The layout would have two child views - A text view and an ImageView.

In your adapter, instead of just setting the text of the text view, you would also set the image source of the ImageView.